# SqlException using database populator with Hibernate and Spring data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to store data into the mysql database through DatabasePopulator during loading of the application. I am using Spring MVC, Hibernate and Spring Data JPA. But I getting some SqlException errors. I have been trying to fix it by change ID generation strategy provided by Hibernate, but without success. 
Thanks in advance. Maybe A need To change something inside my domain object objects. If I populate the code manually everything works fine. But, by using the DataPopulator a run into an error.

Domain Objects

```
 package springmvc.java.domain;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
        private boolean enabled;

        // @ElementCollection
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<BlogPost> blogPosts;

        public User() {

        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

        public List<BlogPost> getBlogPosts() {
            return blogPosts;
        }

        public void setBlogPosts(List<BlogPost> blogPosts) {
            this.blogPosts = blogPosts;
        }

    }




    package springmvc.java.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "blog_post")
    public class BlogPost {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
        private String content;

        // @Column(name = "publishDate", nullable = false)
        @Column(name = "publishDate", nullable = true)
        private Date publishDate;

        @Column(name = "draft", nullable = false)
        private boolean draft;

    //  @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        private User user;

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public Date getPublishDate() {
            return publishDate;
        }

        public void setPublishDate(Date publishDate) {
            this.publishDate = publishDate;
        }

        public boolean isDraft() {
            return draft;
        }

        public void setDraft(boolean draft) {
            this.draft = draft;
        }

    }




package springmvc.java.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "authorities")
    public class Authority {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false)
        private String authority;

        public Authority() {

        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getAuthority() {
            return authority;
        }

        public void setAuthority(String authority) {
            this.authority = authority;
        }

    }




package springmvc.java.config;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "springmvc.java.dao" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("springmvc.java")
public class ApplicationContext {


    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {

        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(false);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/test-insert-data.sql"));

        return databasePopulator;
    }



    /*
     * Second Configuration Option
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource getMySQLDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useSSl=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public BlogPostService blogPostService() {
        return new BlogPostServiceImpl();
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    /*
     * Hibernate Configuration
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(getMySQLDataSource());

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("springmvc.java.domain");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    /*
     * TransactionManager Configuration
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        // The exception is thrown here
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), getMySQLDataSource());

        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

return

The error:

```
    ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [test-insert-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED) VALUES('user','password', TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596) [catalina.jar:8.5.9-dev]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805) [catalina.jar:8.5.9-dev]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [test-insert-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED) VALUES('user','password', TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [test-insert-data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED) VALUES('user','password', TRUE); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:491) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext.transactionManager(ApplicationContext.java:186) ~[classes/:na]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75c8c2da.CGLIB$transactionManager$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75c8c2da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9644c818.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at springmvc.java.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75c8c2da.transactionManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2448) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:470) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Any tip? Really appreciated

Comment: I have edited the code. What do I need to change or fix?

Comment: Update your database and make your `ID` in the `USER` table as `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Comment: Abdullah Khan, the database is created by Hibernate. You can see that all fields are annotated. The GenerationType.AUTO is doing the AUTO INCREMENT,right? Correct me if I am wrong. Is there any way other way to make the id to be AUTO INCREMENTed automatically, not manually?

Comment: `GenerationType.AUTO` itself doesnt create the database and ids for your. The hibernate property `hbm2ddl` does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many posibilities to be failure, sometimes any entity modifications might not be reflected. You should drop and recreate database manually or create new schema and export existing on it.

Other than that you can also use hibernate import_files property to load sql script:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=location_of_sqlfiles_comma_saperated_string'. These statements are only executed if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create or create-drop.
```

Another reason is Generation type:

Take a look at GeneratedValue's strategy. It typically shoud looks something like:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY).
```

You should use Database initialize as given below:

```
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(schemaScript);
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
}
```

Make sure database table was created with auto_increament check

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

In fact, you are trying to populate your database with an SQL script. As your script is executed directly with a connection to the data source, Hibernate isn't used to generate id's column.

You need to add id's values in your SQL script to make it works. Or you have to populate your database by using Hibernate. In your case, it means you can use Spring Data to do the work.

Comment: victor gallet, I have added id's values in SQl, but I got these errors:

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: 
Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of class path resource [test-insert-data.sql]: INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES(ID,USERNAME, AUTHORITY) VALUES(1,'user','ROLE_USER')

Comment: victor gallet, can you, please, provide an example or a tip of how to fill the colums using Spring Data?

Comment: Can you provide your full exception stack trace please ?